# Cannot access androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, what is the meaning of error in Android?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

On which situation android-build/android-studio shows these errors?

> Cannot access androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
>   and 
>   Cannot access androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner

What is the meaning of this errors? I found that adding `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel` as dependency solves these errors, I want to know the meaning of the error in terms of Android Activity LifeCycle(Or is it related to lifecycle or not).

For example in this code call to `super' onSavedInstanceState shows this error

```
public class AppActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);  // Cannot access androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
    }

}
```

When should I use Android Lifecycles,and when should I avoid using it?

Answer (score 14):

add this to your gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

Comment: i try this but not working

Answer (score 5):

Update to the latest appcompat library version can help with this.

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, even after adding the dependencies and having properly migrated to androidx using the one-click refactoring, you would still get intellisense errors against your Kotlin code saying

```
Cannot access 'Cannot access androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner' ...
```

, although the project builds fine.

Then you would have to

1. Quit Android Studio
2. Remove `project/.idea` folder
3. Remove `~/.gradle` folder
4. Restart Android Studio

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` won't work.

Comment: Deleting the files solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: i try this by not working

Answer (score 1):

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` - Worked Actually.

Also I updated the gradle implementations with its latest version release.

Comment: this solution is not working