# Cannot access 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner

Tags: classpath, androidx, lifecycle, conflict

what should I do for handle this error?

I have done it before and it work
now I create new project and faced this error
how can I solve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot access androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, what is the meaning of error in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762145/cannot-access-androidx-lifecycle-lifecycleowner-what-is-the-meaning-of-error-in)

Answer (score -2):

Try some suggest, in Android Studio

Go to:

- File
- Select invalidate caches
- click just restart

Explained in this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762145/cannot-access-androidx-lifecycle-lifecycleowner-what-is-the-meaning-of-error-in)

Comment: this solution is not working